# jQuery Show / Hide Div According to Option Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the div according to the select box selectged item

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7zb705q/1/)

Here i have the following code

```
<select id="test" name="form_select">
   <option value="0" selected>No</option>
   <option value ="1">One</option>
   <option value ="2">Two</option>
   <option value ="3">Three</option>
</select>

<div id="first" style="display: none;">First Div</div>
<div id="second" style="display: none;">Second Div</div>
<div id="third" style="display: none;">Third Div</div>
<div id="none" style="display: none;">Nothing to Displayt</div>
```

And the JS To

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function ()
{
var style = this.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
document.getElementById('none').style.display = style;
}
};
```

What i need is to display the Respective According to the Selection. The Event is wrote is not triggering... What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ?

Comment: does it have to be vanilla js or you can use jquery? because it is a lot easier with jquery.

Comment: If this: http://jsfiddle.net/5vvq5omk/ is what you wanted to do, than you just had a typo there, {} for callback body was missing.

Comment: At the end of the function !!! You , the man !! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have syntactical errors in your code... then

```js
var testel = document.getElementById('test');
testel.addEventListener('change', function() {
  testChange(this.value)
});
//initialize
testChange(testel.value)

function testChange(value) {
  document.getElementById('none').style.display = value == 0 ? 'block' : 'none';;
  document.getElementById('first').style.display = value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';;
  document.getElementById('second').style.display = value == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';;
  document.getElementById('third').style.display = value == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" name="form_select">
  <option value="0" selected>No</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<div id="first" style="display: none;">First Div</div>
<div id="second" style="display: none;">Second Div</div>
<div id="third" style="display: none;">Third Div</div>
<div id="none" style="display: none;">Nothing to Displayt</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a minor syntactical error in the js code. Please find this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7zb705q/7/).

JS Code -

> document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function
>   ()
>       {
>       var style = this.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
>       document.getElementById('none').style.display =style;
>   style = this.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('first').style.display = style;
>
> style = this.value == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
>
> document.getElementById('second').style.display = style;
>
> style = this.value == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
>
> document.getElementById('third').style.display = style;
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You have not put start and close curly braces after starting and you have written

```
 document.getElementById('first').style.display = style;
```

two times, first time it should be none

Update Code:

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function (){ 
   {
      var style = this.value == 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById('none').style.display = style;
   }
   {
      var style = this.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById('first').style.display = style;
   }
   { 
      var style = this.value == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById('second').style.display = style;
   }
   {
      var style = this.value == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById('third').style.display = style;
   }
});
```

Update [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7zb705q/8/)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/h7zb705q/10/

```
var mapping = {
    0: 'none',
    1: 'first',
    2: 'second',
    3: 'third'
};

var allItems = document.querySelectorAll('div');

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function () {
     var toShow = mapping[this.value];

     for(var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
        allItems[i].style.display = 'none';
     };

     document.getElementById(toShow).style.display = 'block';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some thing like this

```
$('.statecontent').hide();
$('#myselector').change(function() {
    $('.statecontent').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();    
});

<div class="statecontent state1">State1 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />
<div class="statecontent state2">State2 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />
<div class="statecontent state3">State3 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />

 <select id="myselector">
 <option value="state1">1</option>
 <option value="state2">2</option>
  <option value="state3">3</option>
 </select>
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr3unv65/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the same  using  `jquery`

http://jsfiddle.net/h9h5858L/1/